# Multiple delimiters in sql loader control file

Tags: sql-loader

I'm new to using sql loader so....
Is there any way I can add multiple delimiters in terminated statement of sql loader control file ? Like if I had two or more delimiters in my data file.
If the data in the file looks something like this 
A;B|C;D|E;F 
I have 2 delimiters here ; and | 
Is there any way I can add both of them in terminated by stmt ?

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this in your existing code

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '|'
```

Comment: Muhammad Waheed it's ignoring the pipe. My input file data is like this 3;ismav|ahcran and  It's inserting like this into the table  3  ismav|ahcran NULL

Comment: load data
infile 'C:\Users\vamshireddy.dasari\Desktop\Book1.csv' 
into table sample_1
append
fields terminated by ';' optionally enclosed by '|' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(sno ,
fname ,
lname)
This is how my control file looks